# Open set contained in $\mathbb{D}^n$ containing $\partial \mathbb{D}^n$

Tags: general-topology

An exercise of topology begins with:

"Let $\mathbb{D}^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : ||x|| \le 1 \}$ and let $U \subset \mathbb{D}^n$ an open set containing $\partial \mathbb{D}^n$..."

How is it possible? If i consider $x \in \partial \mathbb{D^n}$ then $x \in U$ but every $B(x,\varepsilon)$ can't be contained in $U$. And then $U$ is not open.

Maybe the author means "...$U \subset \mathbb{D}^n$ a subset open in the topology induced by the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{D}^n$..."?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're right: use the subspace topology on $\mathbb{D}^n$ induced by the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Author means relatively open, not much harm done, really. The ambient space is $D^n$, so it's understandable.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a beginner in topology and I wanted to be sure!

Comment: Depends on what comes next. Could be a typo, and $U \subset \mathbb R^n$ intended